# Integrating $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$ with the help of a variable change

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals, change-of-variable

The question I am faced with is as follows:

> With the help of a variable change $\sqrt{x^2+1}=x+t$, demonstrate that over $\mathbb{R}$, with $k\in \mathbb{R}$
>
> $$\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} \ \mathrm{d}}x=\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})+k$$

Now what I did was something different, I built a right triangle with an angle $\alpha$ (its adjacent side being $1$ and opposite side being $x$), and with a hypotenuse of $\sqrt{x^2+1}$.

Thus, $x=\tan{\alpha}$ and $\mathrm{d}x=\sec^2{\alpha} \ \mathrm{d}\alpha$. So we have:

$$\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} \ \mathrm{d}}x=\int{\cos{\alpha} \ \mathrm{d}x}=\int{\frac{\sec^2{\alpha}}{\sec{\alpha}}  \ \mathrm{d}\alpha}=\int{\sec{\alpha}  \ \mathrm{d}\alpha}$$

I know how to integrate $\sec{\alpha} \ \mathrm{d}\alpha$, and after replacing $\alpha$ with the initial value of $x$, I indeed end up with the result $\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})+k$.

But how would one end up with the same result using the given hint? Can someone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Square both sides and solve for $x$.  Then you can use $dx=u'(t)\ dt$.

Comment: This is something called an Euler substitution if you want to do further research

Comment: @TehRod Euler substitution turned out to be what I was exactly looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $t=\sqrt{x^2+1}-x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+1}$, which is equivalent to $x=\frac{1-t^2}{2t}$.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int \color{blue}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}}\,\color{red}{dx}&=\int \color{blue}{\left(\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\right)}\,\color{red}{\left(-\frac12 \frac{t^2+1}{t^2}\right)\,dt}\\\\
&=-\int \frac1t\,dt\\\\
&=-\log(t)+k\\\\
&=\log(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})+k
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: @egreg Thank you Greg!  Much appreciative.  -Mark

Answer (score 2):

With $\sqrt{x^2+1}=t-x$ (slightly better) you have $x^2+1=t^2-2tx+x^2$, so
$$
x=\frac{t^2-1}{2t}=\frac{t}{2}-\frac{1}{2t}
$$
so also
$$
dx=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{t^2}\right)\,dt=\frac{t^2+1}{2t^2}\,dt
$$
and
$$
\sqrt{x^2+1}=t-x=t-\frac{t}{2}+\frac{1}{2t}=\frac{t^2+1}{2t}
$$
Then the integral becomes
$$
\int\frac{2t}{t^2+1}\frac{t^2+1}{2t^2}\,dt
$$